# Can emissivity value be 4?

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation, power

We know I=p/A and I=uc which I is radiation density , P is total radiation power , A is surface area and u is energy density. By putting A in the other side we will have p=ucA since energy density is u=aT^4 which radiation constant is a=4σ/c we can conclude p= 4σAT^4(1). By compering (1) and p=εAσT^4 that ε is emissivity we conclude that ε is equal to 4.
why?!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your expression relating $I$ and energy density is wrong. It's actually

$$\frac{P}{A}=I=u\frac{c}{4}$$

which leads you to conclude, from $P=u\frac{c}{4}A$ and $u=\frac{4\sigma}{c}T^4$, that

$$P=\sigma A T^4$$

for a perfect blackbody. Emissivity does not factor into this anywhere, and comparing $P=\sigma AT^4$ (for a perfect blackbody) and $P=\epsilon \sigma A T^4$ (for an imperfect blackbody) does not allow you to conclude that $\epsilon=1$, because the two equations apply to two different objects. The most you can say is that *in the special case of a perfect blackbody*, $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: As you see in this article [https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-9331-4_5]  according to (5.1) formula I=uc . Why is that?

Comment: and also this one http://zuserver2.star.ucl.ac.uk/~idh/PHAS2112/Lectures/Current/Part1.pdf

Comment: First link is broken, and your version doesn't appear in the second link.

Comment: Sorry because of my mistake. This link is correct https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-9331-4_5

Comment: If the formula of energy density in (1.24) is independent of especial frequency and the  solid angle, then the formula will emerge in the second link.